# How do I operate SPI flash with FatFs in small RAM conditions?

Tags: stm32, flash, fat

I want to use SPI flash to store some log files. And I anticipate I can read those files with various devices, so [FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) is my choice.

Now the problem is, my microcontroller only have 16 KBytes of RAM. As most of them are occupied by the application, I can give FatFs at most only 1 KBytes.

SPI flashes usually have a very large erase unit (e.g W25Q64 is 4 Kbytes size). That's the minimum size that FatFs can operate on the SPI flash.

So how do I solve this problem? Or are there other flashes that can be erased in a smaller unit?

Comment: (Micro) SD cards can be flashed in 512 byte units and have SPI support.

Comment: Yes, but that requires more cost and more PCB space.

Comment: I heavily, heavily doubt your cost argument. microSD cards are pretty much the cheapest solid state memory you can buy

Comment: Another argument to go with the uSD card is that it is removable from the product and can be attached to the downwind devices using ready made USB readers. Any scheme to make a discrete SPI flash device externally readable, either by mounting it upon a custom pluggable module or adding an access circuit with connector, is for sure going to cost more and take more space that a uSD card socket.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't describe my system in details, I only need about 4MBytes max, storage such like uSD with very large capacity isn't necessary, spi flash is very cheap, 8MB only costs 0.5$, uSD is much more than that. And I want to use USB in STM32 to allow the PC to access memory directly, so portability isn't a problem. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If your controller handles the external access to the memory, I see no need to use a FAT fs in the first place; except if the controller must emulate a mass storage (block) device...

Comment: Yes, a mass storage device is needed.

Comment: You could go for the AT45DB series (AT45DB641E has a 256/264 byte erase operation). Thus reducing the footprint of the buffer that must be opened in your RAM. And you can easily use it with Chan's FAT-FS. 
Pst. A linux driver is available for this series.